# Getting content from service bus in logic apps

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I am new to Azure logic apps. I have a service bus and pass a json object message to that service bus then I set up an action in logic apps to listen to my service bus. So everytime a new message come in to that service bus my logic apps will pick it up[image] and send it to http.

My question is how can I grab the property from the message in service bus and pass it to my http action.  I tried this

```
“Id” : “@{json(triggerBody()[‘ContentData’]).id}”
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Who and how is sending the message on the queue?

I read a json message property (DestinationPath) in this way:

```
@{json(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData'])).DestinationPath}
```

Here is how my Logic App looks like
[image]

and in my case the message is sent from an Azure webjob as a BrokeredMessage:

```
string jsonMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
Stream streamMessage = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonMessage));
BrokeredMessage msg = new BrokeredMessage(streamMessage);

client.Send(msg);
```

Answer (score 5):

My precise setup to decrypt the base 64 message using the interface. Easy enough to type into the expression builder.

```
json(base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData']))
```

[image: decrypt base 64 service bus message]

Answer (score 0):

ContentData of Service Bus messages is Base64 encoded, so you need to decode it first, e.g.

```
“Id” : “@{json(base64ToString(triggerBody()?[‘ContentData’])).id}”
```

Answer (score 0):

Logic app now has expressions to decode Base 64 encoded value.

My requirement was to decode the encoded ServiceBus message to an Azure Function. I solved this using Logic App Expression, decodeBase64() which can accept a dynamic content of type string, in this case the 'Content'- Content of the message, and returns the decoded json string. 
   ***decodeBase64(triggerBody()?['ContentData'])***

Find attached the screen shots for reference.

[In the place holder for input to the action, include an expression and choose decodeBase64()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kx365.png)

[Get back to Dynamic Content tab to select 'Content' available from previous step, on hitting OK the expression would get generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wvwI.png)