# Azure Logic App service bus message content

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues

I have logic app that is triggered by a service bus.  The message content is not usable as it is just random characters.  I suspect that perhaps it needs to be parsed but it is not clear how to do this.

I have the following:
[Not enough reputation to add an image - but screen shot from Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7YMy.png)

```
 "Insert_Entity": {
            "inputs": {
                "body": {
                    "PartitionKey": "deviceID",
                    "RowKey": "@variables('curDate')",
                    "content": "@triggerBody()?['ContentData']"
                },
```

When I look at the data that I am getting for the "content" coming from the "@triggerBody()?['ContentData']" it looks like this:

"W3sidHlwZSI6ImxvZyJ9LF...."  I deleted most of this as it 100's of characters long.

I suspect that this needs to be parsed or something to look at the actual message body.  I have checked this out but don't know where to insert code like this:  [Getting content from service bus in logic apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43796841/getting-content-from-service-bus-in-logic-apps)

Can you please explain how to see the message body.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Can you please explain how to see the message body.

The string `W3sidHlwZSI6ImxvZyJ9LF....` you mentioned is base64string. If we want to see the message body we need to convert the base64string to string

We could do that with `base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData'])` details please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

**Body info:**

[image]

Comment: you saved my life as I was struggling with DataContractSerializer message types. And this Stream type simply decodes to json from base64

Comment: "body": "@base64ToString(triggerBody()?['ContentData'])",
"headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
},

Answer (score 0):

After getting the value as Tom Sun solution, i had had to extract the json part of the result to be able to parse it, Logic App Expression :

```
substring(
variables('result'),sub(indexOf(variables('result'),'{'),1),
sub(lastIndexOf(variables('result'),'}'),indexOf(variables('result'),'{'))
)
```

Then use Parse JSON function to parse the result using the schema :

```
{
    "properties": {
        "data": {
            "type": "string" // Change As Required
        },
        "dataVersion": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "eventTime": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "eventType": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "metadataVersion": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subject": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "topic": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```