# How to parse a message in Azure IOT hub logic app

Tags: azure, iot, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to understand how to get content into a logic app email (or into the conditioning search in the logic app).

I have an IOT device sending a standard message to the hub (the demo temperature app). This works fine.

I have added a service bus and routing and again all ok.

I then want a logic app to send an email either using some of the content of the message, or even to use the conditional processing in the logic app.

I am using the connector in the logic app to the service bus.

When I try emailing dependant on the conditional "Content contains Startup" the email goes successfully but only down the false route.

When I try to put a JSON parse step in is returns invalid as the content isn't in JSON format.

The Error message:

> InvalidJSON. The 'content' property of actions of type 'ParseJson'
>   must be valid JSON. The provided value
>   'e3sid2ZNZXNzYWdlVHlwZSI6IFN0YXJ0dXAsInRlbXBlcmF0dXJlIjogMzcuMzMsImh1bWlkaXR5IjogNjEuMjV9'
>   cannot be parsed: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing
>   value: e. Path '', line 0, position 0.'.

Comment: Hi there, are you following this documentation?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-routing

Comment: Yes,this documentation does not explain how to parse the message data. It only shows how to email the full content.

Comment: hi, that is a JWT token, you can see the exact value if you decode it, try to decode it in jwt.io. I have the same issue I don't know why the content data is sent as JWT token

Answer (score 1):

It is a little hard to understand exactly where you problem is occurring but it sort of looks like your string is in base64.

You can try converting it using:

```
base64ToString(triggerBody()?['whateveryourvariablenameis'])
```

Check this out for screen shots and more information:
[Azure Logic App service bus message content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47399765/azure-logic-app-service-bus-message-content)